# Why using np.mean() and mean() gave me different output number?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-regression

It is interesting to notice that using np.mean() or mean() gave me different outputs.

```
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ys = np.array([5, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7])

def best_fit_slope(xs, ys):
    numerator = (mean(xs)*mean(ys)) - mean(xs*ys)
    denominator = mean(xs)**2 - mean(xs**2)
    return numerator/denominator 

m = best_fit_slope(xs, ys)
print(m)
```

output>>>
`0.8333333333333334`

But if I replace mean() by np.mean()
the output >>> `0.42857142857142866`.

I followed this video:[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLGfMGsgP34&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=9). He just used mean() and gave an output of 0.42857. Can anyone explain why there is a difference? I know most of the linear algebra operations or that involved in arrays, I would prefer to use np.mean().

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: You have *five* `mean` operations in this.  Which ones return values you didn't expect?  What differences are there in the function definitions?  We expect you to do the basic diagnostic tracing to determine the point of confusion.  "My program gives different output" is more general than we expect of you -- put in some intermediate `print`s to find out where you're confused.

Comment: Interesting `mean` seems to be truncating / rounding. Maybe it calls `np.int64` on the result?

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, this nuance is not explicitly documented in the formal [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean), but it can be deduced from the provided examples.

`statistics.mean` tries its best to provide output of the same type of the input. When you give it `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` (array of `np.int32`) it assumes an `int` output is expected:

```
xs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(mean(xs))
# 3
print(type(mean(xs)))
# <class 'numpy.int32'>
```

It is enough to force one value in the array to `float` to "convince" it we want a `float` back:

```
xs = np.array([1.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# or np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6],dtype=np.float64) or anyother way that gives `dtype` np.float
print(mean(xs))
# 3.5
print(type(mean(xs)))
# <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

If we dig deep enough into its implementation we can see where this behaviour comes from. It is using the `_sum` function which is documented as below:

```
def _sum(data, start=0):
    """_sum(data [, start]) -> (type, sum, count)

    Return a high-precision sum of the given numeric data as a fraction,
    together with the type to be converted to and the count of items.

    If optional argument ``start`` is given, it is added to the total.
    If ``data`` is empty, ``start`` (defaulting to 0) is returned.


    Examples
    --------

    >>> _sum([3, 2.25, 4.5, -0.5, 1.0], 0.75)
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(11, 1), 5)

    Some sources of round-off error will be avoided:

    # Built-in sum returns zero.
    >>> _sum([1e50, 1, -1e50] * 1000)
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(1000, 1), 3000)

    Fractions and Decimals are also supported:

    >>> from fractions import Fraction as F
    >>> _sum([F(2, 3), F(7, 5), F(1, 4), F(5, 6)])
    (<class 'fractions.Fraction'>, Fraction(63, 20), 4)

    >>> from decimal import Decimal as D
    >>> data = [D("0.1375"), D("0.2108"), D("0.3061"), D("0.0419")]
    >>> _sum(data)
    (<class 'decimal.Decimal'>, Fraction(6963, 10000), 4)

    Mixed types are currently treated as an error, except that int is
    allowed.
    """
```

Comment: this is not an array of `int`, but an array with `dtype=numpy.int64` but yeah, that's what's happening, basically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct, but the point still holds. Anyway I'll update the answer

Comment: well, not exactly, because it gives the correct value for a list of int objects, or for that matter, a numpy array of `int` objects (with dtype=object), so it is a bit more subtle

Comment: `np.array([1., 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` is just confusing, you should do `np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6],dtype=np.float64)` or something, or make them all floats.

Comment: denominator = mean(xs)**2 - mean(xs**2) --> check this line, the parenthesis might be creating the difference, and np.mean(number) might be the difference.

Comment: @AndresOrdorica not really. Since `statistics.mean` provides a different output for every  single usage, this error will keep cumulating.

Comment: It is really interesting I just tried the code and the difference , besides statistics bean more precise, is entirely on the numerator and denominator

Comment: 3.5 5.5 20.5 15.166666666666666 -1.25 -2.916666666666666
0.42857142857142866

Comment: 3 5 20 15 -5 -6
0.8333333333333334

Comment: @AndresOrdorica Please read my answer carefully. There is a difference even when calculating `mean(xs)` by itself

Comment: the problem is in the numerator and denominator operations, yes I know the differences, but check your code closely and you will see that the different outputs are made in the numerator and denominator operations. Besides that the difference is in the decimals.

Comment: using numpy the numerator is 3 times smaller than with statistics mean, that is not because of the decimals ....

Comment: @AndresOrdorica Again. My answer clearly shows the difference between `np.mean(xs)` and `statistics.mean(xs)`. One returns `3` while the other return `3.5`. Each and every call to one of them will produce a different  output. Obviously, if there is a difference between every call to one of the `mean` functions, it will only grow with any further/compound call. That is all I'm saying.

Comment: @DeepSpace. Thank you. I did notice in the video that when he defined xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.float64). That is the only difference from my code. Thanks for your quick and clear answer. I didn't expect there would be so much difference regarding the output numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to how the `statistics` package tries to give you consistent outputs depending on the numeric type you pass in, so it handles `int`, `float`, `decimal.Decimal`, `fractions.Fraction` as you would hope. Unfortunately, `numpy` types don't play well with the python numeric type hierarchy. So we can look at the source code (this is the Python version, your runtime is probably using a fast, C version but they should work equivalently...):

```
def mean(data):
    """Return the sample arithmetic mean of data.
    >>> mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
    2.8
    >>> from fractions import Fraction as F
    >>> mean([F(3, 7), F(1, 21), F(5, 3), F(1, 3)])
    Fraction(13, 21)
    >>> from decimal import Decimal as D
    >>> mean([D("0.5"), D("0.75"), D("0.625"), D("0.375")])
    Decimal('0.5625')
    If ``data`` is empty, StatisticsError will be raised.
    """
    if iter(data) is data:
        data = list(data)
    n = len(data)
    if n < 1:
        raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
    T, total, count = _sum(data)
    assert count == n
    return _convert(total/n, T)
```

So, essentially it uses a type-aware `sum`, which returns the type, total, and count. Essentially, the `total/count` is coerced to `T`. Notice:

```
In [28]: T, total, count = statistics._sum(np.array([1,2,3]))

In [29]: T, total, count
Out[29]: (numpy.int64, Fraction(6, 1), 3)

In [30]: total / count
Out[30]: Fraction(2, 1)

In [31]: T(total / count)
Out[31]: 2
```

Notice, all the objects integers you see here are actually `numpy.int64`, not vanilla `int` objects. But why doesn't this happen when we do `statistics.mean([1,2,3,4])`? Well, because the library was built assuming normal python numeric types, peeking at the `_convert` function:

```
def _convert(value, T):
    """Convert value to given numeric type T."""
    if type(value) is T:
        # This covers the cases where T is Fraction, or where value is
        # a NAN or INF (Decimal or float).
        return value
    if issubclass(T, int) and value.denominator != 1:
        T = float
    try:
        # FIXME: what do we do if this overflows?
        return T(value)
    except TypeError:
        if issubclass(T, Decimal):
            return T(value.numerator)/T(value.denominator)
        else:
            raise
```

You'll notice, it special cases: `if issubclass(T, int) and value.denominator != 1`, i.e., you have an `int` and the denominator isn't one, so you want a float:

```
        T = float
```

HOWEVER:

```
In [36]: issubclass(np.int64, int)
Out[36]: False
```

So, `T` is just `np.int64`, and:

```
In [37]: total / count
Out[37]: Fraction(2, 1)

In [38]: np.int64(total / count)
Out[38]: 2
```

Comment: Oh, so lovely to find a `# FIXME` in a production-ready release :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, what's vanilla `int` object?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga & DeepSpace  You guys rock and roll!

Comment: @Yi.D i mean just a regular `int`, `numpy` uses completely different types, and indeed, the array *doesn't actually contain objects of those types*, numpy is essentially an object-oriented wrapper around primitive, numeric, c-like arrays. When you access an element from a numpy arrany, e.g. `array[0]` it *creates* a new Python object each time, and it won't be `int`, it will be somethign like `numpy.int64`. Notice, this is why `array[0] is array[0]` is never true... but for a python list, `mylist[0] is mylist[0]` is always true.